# Question about Packaging in Python with pip

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging

I saw this nice explanation video ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIF3LaRqgXo&t=979s)) of packaging using pip and I got two questions:

The first one is:

I write a code which I want to share with my colleagues, but I do not aim to share it via pypi. Thus, I want to share it internally, so everyone can install it within his/ her environment.

I actually needn't to create a wheel file with `python setup.py bdist_wheel`, right? I create the `setup.py` file and I can install it with the command `pip install -e .` (for editable use), and everyone else can do it so as well, after cloning the repository. Is this right?

My second question is more technical:

I create the `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup 

setup(
    name = 'helloandbyemate',
    version = '0.0.1',
    description="Say hello in slang",
    py_modules=['hellomate'],
    package_dir={"": "src"}
)
```

To test it, I write a file `hellomate.py` which contains a function printing `hello, mate!`. I put this function in `src/`. In the `setup.py` file I put only this module in the list `py_modules`. In `src/` is another module called `byemate.py`. When I install the whole module, it installs the module `byemate.py` as well, although I only put `hellomate` in the list of `py_modules`. Has anyone an explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I actually needn't to create a wheel file ... everyone else can do it so as well, after cloning the repository. Is this right?

This is correct. However, the installation from source is slower, so you may want to publish wheels to an index anyway if you would like faster installs.

> When I install the whole module, it installs the module `byemate.py` as well, although I only put `hellomate` in the list of `py_modules`. Has anyone an explanation for this behaviour?

Yes, this is an artifact of the "editable" installation mode. It works by putting the `src` directory onto the `sys.path`, via a line in the [path configuration file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) `.../lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/easy-install.pth`. This means that the entire source directory is exposed and everything in there is available to import, whether it is packaged up into a release file or not.

- The benefit is that source code is "editable" without reinstallation (adding/removing/modifying files in src will be reflected in the package immediately)
- The drawback is that the editable installation is not exactly the same as a "real" installation, where only the files specified in the `setup.py` will be copied into site-packages directly

If you don't want other files such as `byemate.py` to be available to import, use a regular install `pip install .` without the `-e` option. However, local changes to `hellomate.py` won't be reflected until the installation step is repeated.

#### Strict editable installs

It is possible to get a mode of installation where `byemate.py` is not exposed at all, but live modifications to `hellomate.py` are still possible. This is the ["strict" editable mode](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html#strict-editable-installs) of setuptools. However, it is not possible using `setup.py`, you have to use a modern build system declaration in `pyproject.toml`:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "helloandbyemate"
version = "0.0.1"
description = "Say hello in slang"

[tool.setuptools]
py-modules = ["hellomate"]
include-package-data = false

[tool.setuptools.package-dir]
"" = "src"
```

Now you can perform a strict install with:

```
pip install -e . --config-settings editable_mode=strict
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I got it now. If I understood it right, when I am installing a module it is looking for the wheel file first, when there is no wheel file, it uses the installation from source code automatically, right? This is what it did in my case, since I did not create the wheel file.

Comment: When you install `pip install .` it is always an install from source code. However, the way that pip performs this installation behind the scenes is to first build a wheel from the source code, and then install the wheel. So, it's a little bit of both, in practice.